# std::map not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am trying to use the `std::map` template, but I haven't been able to get it working. From research on the internet I've come to this solution and redirecting the a file to the input stream, here is the code:

```
typedef map<char*, int> wc;
int main() {
    int c;
    char cc[75], nombre[75];
    wc m;
    scanf("%d", &c);
    while (c--) {
        scanf("%s %[ a-zA-Z]", cc, nombre);
        ++m[cc]; // This should work
        printmap(m);
    }
}
```

Print map is a function that just prints the map object. Here is my file input.txt

```
3
Spain Donna Elvira
England Jane Doe
Spain Donna Anna
```

When I execute the program, the ouput is:

```
Spain -> 1
England -> 2
Spain -> 1
```

What I expect is:

```
Spain -> 2
England -> 1
```

The number of occurrences of the Country mapped to the number of times it appears

Comment: Yup, it's doing exactly what you programmed.  It scans in the `cc` and `nombre`, then increases the count for that `cc`, and never does anything with `nombre`.  What's the problem?

Comment: Please don't tell us you are doing `std::map< char*, int >`...

Comment: This really is more of a C question than a C++, minus the fact that he mentioned in passing a possibility of using `std::map`.

Comment: @K-ballo Why not??? hahaha that's exactly what Im doing

Comment: @Andrés: I figured you do... I'll let someone else explain the requirements for an _associative sequence_ key type.

Comment: @Andrés: Why don't I get the same output you did? http://ideone.com/5QBMi  "Spain->3"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a solution to my comment above, the C++ version of the code you presented:

```
typedef map<std::string, int> wc;
int main() {
    int c;
    string cc, nombre;
    wc m;
    std::cin >> c;
    while (c--) {
        std::cin >> cc;
        std::getline(std::cin, nombre);
        m[cc] += 1; // This should work
    }
    printmap(m);
}
```

http://ideone.com/2JP82

First: `std::map` sorts it's data based on the key, in your code, `char*`, which points at `char cc[75]`. So when you replaced the text in `cc`, then the keys of the map changed, and that breaks everything.  The keys of a map *must not change ever*.  Since we're using C++, you should not use `char[]` at all; use `std::string` instead, which (since it is a "value type") will make everything just magically work. I have no idea how it was working before, since you don't show the `printmap` function.

Second: You call `printmap` each and every time you read a single line, and since a `map` has no way of printing "the last thing added", that idea makes no sense at all. The `printmap` call should probably print the entire map, and be outside the loop.

Third: Don't use `scanf`, it's not safe. Use streams: `std::cin >> cc` for reading in a single word, or `std::getline(std::cin, nombre)` for reading in what's left on the line.  That way the code won't crash if someone enters the line (sources for [longest country name](http://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question33835.html) and [longest last name](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081022055524AAXVIOc))

```
Krungthepmahanakornamornratanakosinmahintarayuttha-yamahadilokphopnopparatrajathaniburiromudomrajaniw-esmahasatharnamornphimarnavatarnsathitsakkattiyavi-sanukamprasit Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorffvortschaferswesenchafewarenwholgepflegeunzenvonangereifenduchihrraubgiriigfeindtausendjahresvorandieerscheinenbanderechiffgebrauchlichtalsseinursprungvonkrrthinzwischensternartigraumaufdersuchebtbewohnbarplanetenkreisedrehensichundstandigmenshlichkeittkonntevortpflanzeslamdlichfreudeundruhemitnichteinfurchrintlligentgeschopfsvonhinzwischenster
```

Comment: Although the way the OP uses `scanf` is indeed unsafe, I would not agree that `scanf` is not safe *in general*. Following a very simple rule that the format specifier must provide the limit on the string fixes the safety issue, making the function usable when you prefer C-style I/O (which is also a first-class member of the C++ standard library).

Comment: Most C++ programmers agree that streams are better than `scanf`, for type safety alone.